# Multiple custom info windows using 1 xml layout Maps api v2

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I am trying to display an image inside the custom info window, I have 20 custom info windows the use the same layout but when run the code they all appear exactly the same because they all use the same TextView.

```
            map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter(){

          @Override
          public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
          View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custommarker, null);
         LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
                                                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("Text");
            ll.addView(tv);          
                                                return v;

                                                                }

                                            @Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
return null;        
      }                                     
                                                            });
```

Might I be able to display images in default info windows? If not how would I have all of my Custom marker using this layout,

thanks

Comment: What you want to do? first clear your question

Comment: I would like to be able to use one layout for all of my custom info windows and change text programmatically but when one TextView changes all of them do? Thanks for the Reply:)

Comment: i got you. you just set `Title` to the `Marker` and Get particular `Title` in `Custom Window` when you Click a `Marker`. wait for a while i posting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here i saw you one demo how to implement `Custom Info Window`.

First of all add one `Marker` to `Google Map` like:

```
static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(MELBOURNE)
                      .title("Melbourne")
                      .snippet("Population: 4,137,400"));
```

Now, When you click the `Marker` then `Custom Info Window` trigger and you'll get particular Marker Title using `getTitle()` and Marker snippet using `getSnippet()` like:

```
  map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter(){

      @Override
      public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

      View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custommarker, null);
      LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);

      TextView title = new TextView(this);
      title.setText(marker.getTitle());
      ll.addView(title);   

      TextView snipp = new TextView(this);
      snipp.setText(marker.getSnippet());
      ll.addView(snipp);   

      return v;

    }

     @Override
     public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
        return null;        
    }                                     
  });
```

**Output:** When you click into `Marker` then `Custom Info Window` display like:

[image]

**Update:** your app getting crash it's becoz of this

```
 LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
```

Change to

```
 LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.ll);
```

your `LinearLayout` coming from inflated layout.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code

```
        MarkerOptions MarkerT = new MarkerOptions().snippet("Hello");
                                                       MarkerT.title(postc.getAuthor());
                                                       MarkerT.position(new LatLng(postc.getLat(), postc.getLong()));
                                                       MarkerT.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp));

                                                       Marker marker = map.addMarker(MarkerT);
                                                       map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter(){

                                                              @Override
                                                              public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                                                              View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custommarker, null);
                                                              LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);

                                                            ink(marker.getSnippet(),ll);   

                                                              return v;

                                                            }

                                                             @Override
                                                             public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                                                                return null;        
                                                            }                                     
                                                          });
```

This causes a crash and I'm unsure why, Thanks for the reply:)
ink = method that creates a textView.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how would I set an image inside the marker info window?

Comment: Thanks Very much, How might I display an image in these info windows with out having the same problem with the textViews?